# Fabric Hyperledger Deploying Chaincode failed - javascript

Tags: bash, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, chaincode

I am trying to run fabric chaincode after network.ch up but the below error is coming, trying hard to find a solution, appreciate much for your help

```
$ ./network.sh deployCC -ccn basic -ccp ../asset-transfer-basic/chaincode-javascript -ccl javascript
/c/Users/user/fab/fabric-samples/test-network/configtx/configtx.yaml
./network.sh: line 28: pushd: too many arguments
Using docker and docker-compose
deploying chaincode on channel 'mychannel'
executing with the following
- CHANNEL_NAME: mychannel
- CC_NAME: basic
- CC_SRC_PATH: ../asset-transfer-basic/chaincode-javascript
- CC_SRC_LANGUAGE: javascript
- CC_VERSION: 1.0
- CC_SEQUENCE: 1
- CC_END_POLICY: NA
- CC_COLL_CONFIG: NA
- CC_INIT_FCN: NA
- DELAY: 3
- MAX_RETRY: 5
- VERBOSE: false
+ peer lifecycle chaincode package basic.tar.gz --path ../asset-transfer-basic/chaincode-javascript --lang node --label basic_1.0
+ res=0
++ peer lifecycle chaincode calculatepackageid basic.tar.gz
+ PACKAGE_ID=basic_1.0:e4b11f4369fabe9b787459fc5acdefbb6c48f77637b2614b13e103b4528d88ed
Chaincode is packaged
Installing chaincode on peer0.org1...
Using organization 1
+ peer lifecycle chaincode queryinstalled --output json
+ jq 'try (.installed_chaincodes[].package_id)'
scripts/ccutils.sh: line 9: jq: command not found
+ grep '^basic_1.0:e4b11f4369fabe9b787459fc5acdefbb6c48f77637b2614b13e103b4528d88ed$'
+ test 1 -ne 0
+ peer lifecycle chaincode install basic.tar.gz
+ res=0
2022-09-18 10:49:02.425 IST 0001 INFO [cli.lifecycle.chaincode] submitInstallProposal -> Installed remotely: response:<status:200 payload:"\nJbasic_1.0:e4b11f4369fabe9b787459fc5acdefbb6c48f77637b2614b13e103b4528d88ed\022\tbasic_1.0" >
2022-09-18 10:49:02.426 IST 0002 INFO [cli.lifecycle.chaincode] submitInstallProposal -> Chaincode code package identifier: basic_1.0:e4b11f4369fabe9b787459fc5acdefbb6c48f77637b2614b13e103b4528d88ed
Chaincode is installed on peer0.org1
Install chaincode on peer0.org2...
Using organization 2
+ peer lifecycle chaincode queryinstalled --output json
+ jq 'try (.installed_chaincodes[].package_id)'
scripts/ccutils.sh: line 9: jq: command not found
+ grep '^basic_1.0:e4b11f4369fabe9b787459fc5acdefbb6c48f77637b2614b13e103b4528d88ed$'
+ test 1 -ne 0
+ peer lifecycle chaincode install basic.tar.gz
+ res=0
2022-09-18 10:49:31.056 IST 0001 INFO [cli.lifecycle.chaincode] submitInstallProposal -> Installed remotely: response:<status:200 payload:"\nJbasic_1.0:e4b11f4369fabe9b787459fc5acdefbb6c48f77637b2614b13e103b4528d88ed\022\tbasic_1.0" >
2022-09-18 10:49:31.057 IST 0002 INFO [cli.lifecycle.chaincode] submitInstallProposal -> Chaincode code package identifier: basic_1.0:e4b11f4369fabe9b787459fc5acdefbb6c48f77637b2614b13e103b4528d88ed
Chaincode is installed on peer0.org2
Using organization 1
+ peer lifecycle chaincode queryinstalled --output json
+ jq -r 'try (.installed_chaincodes[].package_id)'
scripts/ccutils.sh: line 25: jq: command not found
+ grep '^basic_1.0:e4b11f4369fabe9b787459fc5acdefbb6c48f77637b2614b13e103b4528d88ed$'
+ res=1
Query installed on peer0.org1 has failed
Deploying chaincode failed
scripts/utils.sh: line 1: popd: directory stack empty
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the command apt-get install -y jq
to clear out the jq: command not found. worked for me. Unsure of any other issues, but this will resolve that.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).